# Does express-handlebars keep its variables hidden from the client after using res.render()?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, handlebars.js

I assume all variables and data used to mark up the page which is to be rendered are not sent to the client unless {{}} is used. For example, can you use {{user.name}} without it revealing all the other data associated with the object user? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, all that data in templates is only used when generating markup/HTML in the backend before responding to the request. So, in short, the user will never see the data. However, I can't say for sure this is true for setups that compile on the Frontend.